# How to show plot or graphics on Form or PictureBox in NETLink?

Tags: plotting, .netlink

How to show the plot or graphics on the image property of a form or picturebox with NETLink?

```
(*plotting*)
p1 = Plot[Sin[x],{x,-4,4}];

Needs["NETLink`"];
InstallNET[];

frm = NETNew["System.Windows.Forms.Form"];
frm@BackgroundImage = ReturnAsNetObject@Rasterize[p1] (*not work*)
ShowNETWindow[frm]
```

`ReturnAsNetObject` does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... What to do is to follow the .NET rule to make it.

```
loadImage[plot_] :=
    Module[ {result},
        (*produce file*)
        file = CreateTemporary[];
        Export[file, plot, "GIF"];

        (*get object*)
        LoadNETType["System.Drawing.Image"];
        result = Image`FromFile[file];

        (*clean*)
        DeleteFile[file];(*may catch Privilege problem*)
        (*return as object*)
        Return[result];
    ]
```

then pass the object produced to the property.

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4, 4}];

Needs["NETLink`"];
InstallNET[];

LoadNETType["System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout"];

frm = NETNew["System.Windows.Forms.Form"];
frm@Width = 500;
frm@Height = 300;
frm@BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout`Stretch;
frm@BackgroundImage = loadImage[p1]; (*now ok*)

ShowNETWindow[frm]
```

[image]

However, I don't know would it be efficient on large projects.

Update: use `FileStream` to avoid priviledge problem.

```
loadImage2[plot_] :=
 NETBlock@Module[{fs, result},
   (*produce file*)
   file = CreateTemporary[];
   Export[file, plot, "GIF"];

   (*get object*)
   LoadNETType["System.Drawing.Image"];
   LoadNETType["System.IO.FileMode"];
   LoadNETType["System.IO.FileAccess"];

   fs = NETNew["System.IO.FileStream", file, FileMode`Open, 
     FileAccess`Read];
   result = Image`FromStream[fs];

   (*clean*)
   fs@Close[];
   DeleteFile[file];
   (*return as object*)
   Return[result];
   ]
```